# Flash CS6 / AS 3.0 - How to pause/play sound embedded in keyframe?

Tags: flash, actionscript, jquery-animate

I am using the Keyframe > Properties > Sound to add voiceovers to my animation. I have several of these sound clips on a single layer. I also have a pause (btn_pause) and play (btn_play) button that uses the following code:

```
btn_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, animPlay);
btn_pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, animPause);

 function animPlay(event:MouseEvent): void {

 play();  }

function animPause(event:MouseEvent): void {

 stop();  }
```

Above code works perfectly when there was still no sound (the voiceovers were a very late addition). However everything went downhill after the inclusion of the sound clips. It pauses, yes. But only after the entirety of the soundclip has finished playing.

I also read somewhere here in stackoverflow that it is possible to stop the sound if the Properties > Sync is set to "Stream". However, my Sync is only limited to "Event". I am using an HTML5 Canvas, if that helps. I hope someone can help me with this, thanks!

Comment: So your choice seems to be limited to making global volume of the sound channel to 0 when pause.

Comment: Stream would do it as then the sound is synchronizing with the timeline. If the timepline play stops, the sound would stop as well. Actually it is preferably to use stream as this is the only way to make sure the sound is in sync with the animation (it might get out of sync depending on the machine's speed, current load etc). If that's not an option another way is to create a sound programmatically rather than adding it to the timeline. Then you could also pause / play this specific sound